# Laravel Form Submit should only work with submit button in livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

First I create a form and wire it to function But it have two button and one button for form submit and other one for reset everything. But if any button press it will submit after run resetcategory() function  but after it run submitcategory() i can't get i use some workaround with if($this->name) but i don't want to use that. Please Help?

My php livewire file is

```
public function resetcategory()
{
    $this->reset();
}

public function submitcategory()
{
     if ($this->name)
    {
    Category::create([
        'name' => $this->name,
        'parent' => $this->parent,
    ]);
    $this->reset();
    }
}
```

my blade file is---

```
 <form wire:submit.prevent="submitcategory">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-end px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6 shadow sm:rounded-bl-md sm:rounded-br-md">
        <!-- here is input content-->
        <button class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-900 focus:ring focus:ring-gray-300 disabled:opacity-25 transition mr-2 ml-2" wire:click="resetcategory()">Reset</button>
    
        <button type="submit" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-900 focus:ring focus:ring-gray-300 disabled:opacity-25 transition">Send</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because you have not specified a `type` on your `Reset` button. The default `type` for a button (if a `type` is not provided) is `submit`. So your reset button is actually submitting the form too.

Add `type="button"` on your `Reset` button to prevent it submitting the form.

```html
<button type="button" wire:click="resetcategory()">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Great answer! Makes so much sense, but I wasnt seeing it.